# How to move image disk of a filesystem to a partition

Tags: partition, disk

I have a linux.img file with Arch Linux installed on it. I use the linux.img file to boot Archlinux on virtual machine. I got a new PC and will like to move the linux.img to new PC and boot it from a partitioned disk. How do I move the image disk system file(linux.img) to a partition disk without loosing the files inside the linux.img?

Comment: I have updated my question. the file linux.img is a single filesystem that I use to boot Arch Linux on virtual machine.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a Virtual Machine image to a physical machine ?

Comment: @don_crissti, something like that. I don't know if it will work though. I finally decided to install a fresh OS and move my backup files.

Comment: I've already voted for reopening this question. You need two more votes... Just try to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

What is the linux.img an image of?

### Single Filesystem

If it is an image of a filesystem (e.g. ext4), you can create a partition (of size greater or equal) and use

```
dd if=linux.img of=<new partition> bs=4M
resize2fs <new partition> # if needed
```

(as root, so you may need sudo). The resize2fs command (with no options besides the ) will grow that filesystem to fit its partition.

Alternatively, if you only wish to copy the files, make a new partition, mount via loopback, and use two tar's and a pipe, or rsync.

Example 1

```
sudo -s # ensure we are running as root
mkdir /tmp/a
mkdir /tmp/b
mount -o loop linux.img /tmp/a
mount /dev/sdx1 /tmp/b # where sdx1 is the target partition
cd /tmp
( cd a; tar cf -) | ( cd b; tar xvf - )
```

Example 2

```
sudo -s # ensure we are running as root
mkdir /tmp/a
mkdir /tmp/b
mount -o loop linux.img /tmp/a
mount /dev/sdx1 /tmp/b # where sdx1 is the target partition
rsync -haux /tmp/a/ /tmp/b/
```

### Image of partitioned drive

If, however, the linux.img is the image of a partitioned drive  -- that is, like something obtained from a command along the lines of

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=my.img bs=4M
```

then you will need to create multiple partitions and repeat the above procedure for each partition (potentially using a script to automate the process).

Comment: The file is an image of a filesystem. Thanks @John Allsup